# Как ограничить ширину внешнего элемента одним из внутренних?

Tags: html, css

В примере ниже, есть `tbl2`. Как сделать так, что бы `div.main` имел ширину таблицы `tbl2`? Что бы `inline-block` элементы (несколько `div` ниже) не растягивали его, а переносились на следующую строку?

В примере ниже `inline4` должен перенестись на другую строку, а ширина `div.main` должна стать равна `table.tbl2`.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tbl1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.tbl2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tbl2 td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.inline-div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">

    <table class="tbl1">
      <tr>
        <td>text text text text</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="tbl2">
      <tr>
        <td>text 1</td>
        <td>text 2</td>
        <td>text 3</td>
        <td>text 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="inline-div">inline1</div>
    <div class="inline-div">inline2</div>
    <div class="inline-div">inline3</div>
    <div class="inline-div">inline4</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Вы не можете наследовать ширину отдельного элемента, чтобы передать ее всем остальным и родителю без JS. Вам нужно указать `max-width` для класса `main`.

Второй вариант обвернуть `inline-div` в обертку и задать ей `max-width`

Comment: Если делать напрямую, то да, никак. На англоязычном стековерфлов предложили такой хак: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930904/how-to-fix-parent-element-width-to-one-of-its-child

Comment: Неплохо :) Костыль, но зато какой.